# How to get user role on symfony 2.8.28 from a listener

Tags: symfony, service, event-listener, symfony-2.8

I have a event listener:

```
services:
    app.game.listener.gamestatus:
        class: GameBundle\EventListener\Game\GameStatusListener
        arguments:
            - '@servicexy'
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.controller, method: onFilterControllerEvent }
```

Which service must pass like argument to get user and its role ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can typehint `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface` into a service constructor and from there,

```
$user = $this->token->getToken()->getUser();
$roles = $user->getRoles();
```

It's '@security.token_storage' if you are injecting it manually.